# How to connect one page with another page in landing page of django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have one landing page. I want to separate them and divide them in different pages so that whenever I make changes in it, I don't have to search a long index.html page. How to do this? I made changes but it is not working because in `<div>`  it has `id` which I don't know how to reach?

**views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request)
        first = request.POST.get('first', '')
        last = request.POST.get('last', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        textarea = request.POST.get('textarea', '')
        print(first, last, email, textarea)
    return render(request, 'home/contact.html')
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mb-5">
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last" placeholder="Full name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <textarea name="textarea" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your message." cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mr-auto">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-white py-2 px-5" value="Send Message">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use `include` template tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Answer (score 0):

**Here is solution**

```
 <a href="{%url 'contact'%}" > Contact </a>
```

Comment: It is not as simple. I am working on one landing page. but it has different pages. Whenever I click on one page. It scrolls down to show me that section. I want this section to be present in browser landing but be on another file not in **index.html**

Comment: you are asking about template inheritance, and the clicking page and scrolling down, that is html linking a section from anchor tag, here is a link regarding this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/basic-html-and-html5/link-to-internal-sections-of-a-page-with-anchor-elements

Comment: You're right but I want my one page of contact to be separated in coding but be present on that landing page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to write that section from index.html to individual html file

Example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...title...
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            ...section 1...
        </div>
        <div>
            ...section 2...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, split those section into individual html file as...

**section1.html**

```
<div>
     ...section 1...
</div>
```

**section2.html**

```
<div>
     ...section 2...
</div>
```

Now, remove your section 1 and section 2 from `index.html` and at same place include this `section1.html` and `section2.html` as below...

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...title...
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        {% include "section1.html" %}
        {% include "section2.html" %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```